# Why Is My Chrome-Specific Media Query Being Overridden?

Tags: html, css

As you can see below, I have two media queries. One for all non-Chrome browsers, and one for Chrome exclusively.

However, despite having two separate media queries, the style always defaults to, and is overridden by the the Chrome specific media query.

Why is it doing this, and how do I prevent it?

Thank you.

```
 @media (max-width: 1050px) {
       .menu-vertical-active::before{
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
          right: 300px;
          bottom: 150px;
          width: 7px;
          height: 20px;
          background: red;
          border-radius: 0px;
           transform: unset;
          transform-origin: unset;
        }
    }


@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (max-width: 1050px) {
       .menu-vertical-active::before{
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
          right: 145px;
          bottom: 140px;
          width: 7px;
          height: 20px;
          background: red;
          border-radius: 0px;
           transform: unset;
          transform-origin: unset;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 /*this works in my case:*/
.menu-vertical-active::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute !important;
  right: 300px !important;
  bottom: 150px !important;
  width: 7px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
  background: red !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  transform: unset !important;
  transform-origin: unset !important;
}
```